# Mover game object por su RectTransform [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Estoy intentando hacer un prototipo para un juego de cartas tipo Hearthstone. Cada vez que el jugador consigue una carta para su mano, instancio un prefab "carta" que tiene la jerarquía que se muestra en la imagen.

La cosa es que me gustaría que cada carta que se instanciase nueva, se instanciase un poco mas a la derecha que la anterior (como si la estuvieses cogiendo y poniéndola en tu mano de verdad).

El problema viene en que no se que parametro exactamente modificar del gameObject para transformar su posicion. He intenado mover el RectTransform del panel que incluye el resto de componentes de la siguiente manera:

```
case 1:
            _transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x +200, 0, 0);

            break;
```

En este caso simplemente estaría intentando mover el gameobject 200 unidades más a la derecha de su posición original.

[image: Jerarquia del prefab Carta]

Comment: En los foros de Unity hay un montón de preguntas ya respondidas, así como tutoriales y guias que te pueden ayudar (además del contenido de Youtube). No es que no puedas encontrar ayuda aquí... es que estás preguntando cosas muy específicas de Unity y aunque aquí seguro que hay quien conozca Unity y trabaje con ello, en los foros de Unity **todos** conocen Unity :)

Comment: @Benito-B probaré a preguntar ahí, gracias